# Hide Columns in DataGridView by field reference not column string name

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview

I am writing a program where data is being displayed using a DataGridView and I was hoping there was a way to access the visible property of the columns without specifying the index location, or Column Name string value.

```
public class test {
    public static string value1 { get; set; }
    public static string value2 { get; set; }
}
```

I am using the LINQ to SQL datacontext to query information to be displayed into my DataGridView.

As it currently is, I can only seem to find a way to change the Columns visible property as so (assuming DataGridView is instantiated as dgvDATA)

```
dgvDATA.columns["value1"].visible = false;
```

Is there any way to do something similar to the following? I assume if there is it would be through databindings, but I tried that and couldn't figure it out.

```
dgvDATA.column.value1.visible = false;
```

I found this article stating that the DataGridView does not have this kind of ability built in but there was a workaround where you could add a database field representing if you want it visible or not.

HOWEVER the article was written in 2011 so I find it hard to believe that something like this was never implemented.

https://dotnetbuildingblocks.wordpress.com/2011/07/30/binding-datagrid-column-visibility-to-a-datacontext/

Please let me know if this is possible! Thank you

Comment: DataGridView.Columns returns a DataGridViewColumnCollection object which has properties to access collection object using index or name only. I don't think this is possible. However Can i know why you want to access it that way?

Comment: I am wanting to do this due to refactoring reasons. If we have to change the database field name, it would be easier to just reactor the field name in my class other than searching for string representations of that column.

Comment: It's unclear what your requirement is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataGridView` doesn't support what you are asking for.

Anyway, if your only goal is to avoid using hardcoded field names, then using `nameof()` makes sense.

In your case it will be

`dgvDATA.Columns[nameof(test.value1)].Visible = false;`

That way you will have no issues refactoring your code later.

Comment: YOU SIR ARE A LIFESAVER. I have been looking how to do that for a while now, and all of my google searches never told me that existed. They always said I had to go get the type and have bindingflags and stuff. How simple can this be. I am either the worlds worst googler or have the worst luck until I met you!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you want some kind of special `DataGridViewColumn`, where columns can be identified using some identification that is not available in a standard `DataGridViewcolumn`. For example you want to identify them by the `PropertyInfo` of the property that is shown in the column, or maybe the database column name of the database column whose values you show in this column.

In object oriented programming, if you want to create a special kind of `DataGridViewColumn` you should write a derived class:

```
class MySpecialDataGridViewColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
    public string DatabaseColumnName {get; set;}
}
```

Normally this would be enough: as long as you make sure that you only add `MySpecialDataGridViewColumn` objects to your `DataGridView`. When you fetch a column, typecast it to `MySpecialDataGridViewColumn`.

```
var theColumnThatDisplaysFirstName = myDataGridView.Columns    // get all columns
       .Cast<MySpecidalDataGridViewColumn>()                   // cast to your type
       .Where(column => column.DatabaseCollumnName == "FirstName")
       .SingleOrDefault();                                     // keep the ones with "FirstName"
```

Be aware that others will still be able to Add other kind of columns to your `DataGridView`. If you are afraid of this, make sure that you keep your members private and add functionality to Add / Fetch / Remove `MySpecialDataGridViewColumns`.

If your `DataGridView` is to be used by many, consider creating a `UserControl` that contains a private `DataGridView`, with functionalities to Add / Retrieve / Remove `MySpecialDataGridViewColumn` objects to the user control. This way others can't misuse your `DataGridView by adding other types of columns

Of course, if you want to allow others to add their own kind of Columns, you could always use `OfType<MySpecialDataGridViewColumn>` instead of a `Cast`. This way you ignore the other type of added columns, of which you are certain that they don't display your database columns